# Yet another inequality: $|a+b|^p<2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers and $p>0$. What is the best way to prove that $|a+b|^p<2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you divide $2^p$ on both sides, then you get $(|a+b|/2)^p < |a|^p + |b|^p$. Can you see why that would be true?

Comment: lol, that's really very easy

Answer (score 6):

Well,

\begin{align*}
|a + b|^p \leq (|a| + |b|)^p &\leq 2^p \text{max}\{|a|^p, |b|^p\}\\
&\leq 2^{p - 1} (|a|^p + |b|^p - |a^p - b^p|)\\
&\leq 2^{p - 1} (|a|^p + |b|^p)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

If $0<p\leq1$ you don't need any powers of $2$.  This came up in another [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10993/please-explain-inequality-xp-yp-leq-x-yp).  If $1\leq p$ you can strengthen the inequality to $|a+b|^p\leq 2^{p-1}(|a|^p+|b|^p)$ by applying convexity of the function $t\mapsto t^p$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative for the case $p\ge1$ we may also use Hölder's inequality
$$|a+b|=|1\cdot a +1\cdot b|\leq (1^q+ 1^q)^{1/q}(|a|^p+|b|^p)^{1/p}=2^{1/q}(|a|^p+|b|^p)^{1/p}$$
where $1/q+1/p=1$, which reduces to
$$|a+b|^p\le 2^{p/q}(|a|^p+|b|^p)=2^{p(1-1/p)}(|a|^p+|b|^p)=2^{p-1}(|a|^p+|b|^p).$$
For $0<p<1$, please see my answer in the thread ["Please explain inequality $|x^p−y^p|\le|x−y|^p$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10993/please-explain-inequality-xp-yp-leq-x-yp)