# $\int |f+g|^p \leq \int |f|^p + \int |g|^p$ for $p>0$ and $f, g \in L^p$?

Tags: measure-theory

$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, u)$ is a measure space, and $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, u)$ is its $L^p$ space. Define $N_p(f) = \int_{\Omega} |f|^p\, d\mu$. $\forall f, g \in L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, u)$,

1. when $0<p<1$, $N_p(f+g) \leq
       N_p(f)+N_p(g) $ is true according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_for_0_.3C_p_.3C_1). This can help to show that     $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, u)$ is a
   vector space. I was wondering how to
   prove the inequality is true?
2. when $p \geq 1$, is the inequality
   $N_p(f+g) \leq N_p(f)+N_p(g) $ still true?

   If not,

   (1) can the inequality be modified to be true?
   Note I am not asking about the
   triangle inequality of $L^p$ norm.

   (2) how can one show that $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, u)$ is a
   vector space?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: For 2, consider $p=2$ with positive $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. This holds because $(a+b)^p\leq a^p+b^p$ when $0<p<1$, $a\geq 0$, and $b\geq 0$, as seen for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11849/w-1w-2-cdotsw-na-leq-w-1a-cdots-w-na-for-n-integer-n-geq-2/11851#11851).
2. Not if $p>1$. For $p\geq 1$ you have $(a+b)^p\leq 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$ when $a\geq0$ and $b\geq 0$.  This can be proved by rearranging the inequality 
   $\displaystyle \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^p\leq\frac{1}{2}(a^p+b^p)$, 
   which follows from convexity of the function $x\mapsto x^p$.  You need the factor of $2^{p-1}$, as can be seen by taking $a=b=1$.  A less sharp version was asked about [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11122/yet-another-inequality).

Comment: Thanks! So (1) when $p\geq 1$, $N_p(f+g) \leq 2^{p−1} (N_p(f) + N_p(g))$? (2) when $0<p<1$, is $N_p(f+g) \leq 2^{p−1} (N_p(f) + N_p(g))$ true? (3) when $0<p<1$, is there a sharper one than $N_p(f+g) \leq N_p(f) + N_p(g)$?

Comment: (1) Yes, because $|f+g|^p\leq 2^{p-1}(|f|^p+|g|^p)$ holds pointwise. (2) No.  Notice that $2^{p-1}<1$ in that case, and consider what happens when $g=0$. (3) No.  Again consider what happens when $g=0$.