# The function $f(x) = x^\alpha $ belongs to the Lipschitz class of order $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, holder-spaces

Given a function $f$ and a constant $M \ge 0$ such that:

$$ |f(x_1) - f(x_2) |\le M {|x_1 - x_2|}^{\alpha} $$

we say that $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition of order $\alpha$. We denote by Lip $\alpha$ the set of all such functions. Consider the following problem:

> For $\alpha \in (0,1)$, show that $f(x) = x^{\alpha} $ belongs to Lip $\alpha $.

**My proof**

Suppose $f(x_1) = x_1^\alpha $ and $f(x_2) = x_2^\alpha $ and then $$ |f(x_1) - f(x_2) | = |x_1^\alpha - x_2^\alpha|\le |x_1 - x_2|^\alpha $$ where $x_1 \ne x_2$.

Note that $ |x_1^\alpha - x_2^\alpha|\le |x_1 - x_2|^\alpha\le M|x_1 - x_2|^\alpha  $

Hence, $f(x) = x^\alpha $ belongs to Lip $\alpha$.

Is there anything wrong with my proof? If so please let me know!

Comment: Your way you are doing your proof is not right. First at all you have to prove that $|x^\alpha-y^\alpha|\leq M|x-y|^\alpha$. Try to use some usual inequality to prove it.

Comment: Ok , I guess I have shown  $|x - y|^\alpha \le M |x-y|^\alpha $ above. Then how do I continue?

Comment: I don't understand why you begin from $f(x_1)=x_1$... You have that $f(x)=x^\alpha$.

Comment: Ah Ok, so then I will start with $x^\alpha$ and I will edit my approach. Please have a look at my approach a few min later.

Comment: @YotasTrejos I have shown what you have told me to prove. How do I continue now? Thanks a lot though!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please explain inequality $|x^{p}-y^{p}| \leq |x-y|^p$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10993/please-explain-inequality-xp-yp-leq-x-yp)

Comment: When you say "note that $|x_1^\alpha - x_2^\alpha|\le |x_1 - x_2|^\alpha$" ... how did you "note" this. This inequality is  the statement to be proved here. See the link above.