# Examples of $\alpha$-Lipschitz functions for $ \alpha > 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

The question: [The function $f(x) = x^\alpha $ belongs to the Lipschitz class of order $\alpha$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039129/the-function-fx-x-alpha-belongs-to-the-lipschitz-class-of-order-alpha) gives an example of $\alpha$-lipschitz function for $\alpha \in ]0,1[$. This is $x^{\alpha}$.

I guess this does not hold when $\alpha > 1$. What is an easy argument to show this? Also, what are examples of $\alpha$-Lipstchitz functions when $\alpha > 1$?

Recall $\alpha$-Lipschitz means there is a $K$ such that $\|f(x)-f(y) \| \le K \| x-y \|^{\alpha}$.

Comment: $\alpha$-lipstchitz for $\alpha > 1$ implies constant. Indeed, it's easy to show the derivative is always 0.

Comment: See also the anecdote [here](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/definitions-definitions-do-we-need-them/) on this class of functions... paragraph "What is a nice function?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct name is $\alpha$-Hölder, not Lipschitz. Lipschitz refers to the case $\alpha=1$. Anyway, for $\alpha>1$, you can show that $\alpha$-Hölder functions defined on "good sets" (see below) are constant.

---

Assume that $E$ is a convex set. Obviously, $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ or open balls in these spaces all are convex sets.

$\forall y \in E$, our assumption implies
$$\forall x\in E: \,\,\,\|f(x)-f(y) \| \le K \| x-y \|^{\alpha}$$

From the properties of real numbers we know that when $\alpha>1$,

$$\forall r\in\mathbb{R}:0<r<1 \implies r^{\alpha}<r$$

Now given $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta=\frac{1}{2}\min\{1,\frac{2\epsilon}{K}\}$. This ensures that $\delta < 1$ holds. Therefore,

$$\| x-y \|< \delta \implies \| x-y \|^{\alpha}<\delta^{\alpha}<\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{K}$$

$$\|f(x)-f(y) \| \le K \| x-y \|^{\alpha} < K \frac{\epsilon}K = \epsilon$$

Since the above inequality is true for all $\epsilon >0$, we get $\|f(x)-f(y) \|=0$ when $\|x-y\|< \delta$.

Hence $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x\in E \cap B_{\delta}(y)$ for all $y\in E$, i.e. $f$ is *locally constant*.

If $d(x,y) \geq \delta$, since $d(x,y)$ is a finite number and $E$ is convex, you can choose $n$ points $\{z_0=x,z_1,\cdots,z_n=y\} \in E$ to connect $x$ to $y$ such that $$d(z_i,z_{i+1})<\delta \text{ for } i=0,1,\cdots,n-1$$

Then $\forall i\in\{1,\cdots,n-1\}: \,f(x)=f(z_i)=f(y)$, which means that $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x,y \in E$. Hence, $f$ is constant on $E$.

---

**Generalization to connected sets**

Using the theorem in topology that *[locally constant functions on connected spaces are constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44850/locally-constant-functions-on-connected-spaces-are-constant)*, we can assume $E$ to be connected only. Our argument will be simplified then. We won't need intermediate points anymore. Instead, we argue that we have shown $f$ to be locally constant at each point $y \in E$. Since $E$ is connected, it must be constant on all of $E$.

---

**An example of a bad set**

To see an example of a bad set $E$, take $E = (-\infty,-1] \cup [+1,+\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $f: E \to \{\pm 1\}$ be 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} +1 & \text{if}\, x\geq +1 \\ -1 & \text{if}\, x\leq -1\end{cases}$$

Then the assumptions of being $\alpha$-Hölder are satisfied for $K=1$, but $f$ is not constant obviously. So, more generally, one can say that if $E$ has several connected components, then $f$ is constant on each connected component.

Comment: You *really* need to say what $E$ is to make this valid.

Comment: @UmbertoP. You're exactly right. I was editing my answer before I read your comment. So, I'm glad that my suspicion wasn't wrong. I think $E$ has to be convex, but maybe a weaker assumption that $E$ is star-shaped works too.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I just realized that we can use the theorem that says *locally constant functions on connected sets are constant* instead. So, if $E$ is connected, then the proof still works. Am I correct?

Comment: i really appreciate your detailed answer. the name i was giving comes from the lectures notes from a fractal geometry course i folllow. it is precisely stated in the notes although not explicit in the accompanying book (by the same author). Anyway I would appreciate if there are any references you can recommend on alpha-holder functions. i feel this kind of functions will come into play in a later course on differential equations i have to take

Comment: @Javier You're welcome. I don't know a resource specifically on $\alpha$-Hölder functions. I don't know if there's an independent theory about them or not. I personally find Wikipedia entries on them very comprehensive but you have to prove the claims on your own. One interesting case is $\alpha=1$ which gives Lipschitz functions that are absolutely continuous. Another interesting case that I remember from a course on stochastic differential equations is for $\alpha=1/2$. It turns out that Brownian motion approximately satisfies $|W(t)-W(s)| \approx |t-s|^{1/2}$ when $t$ and $s$ are very close

Comment: @Javier Brownian motion, which is called the Wiener process in mathematics, is the basis of stochastic calculus. It turns out that unlike the cases when $\alpha\geq 1$ which make the function (almost everywhere) differentiable, Brownian motion is almost everywhere continuous while being nowhere differentiable. So, when $0<\alpha<1$ things seem to be more interesting.